# How to integrate gmail with salesforce for placing the Attachments dynamically?

Tags: custom-button, attachment

I have one button in my Custom Object.

1. **`Generate PDF`**

Whenever i click this button, the PDF will be generated... This is a post scenario of my requirement. But Present, They want another button for sending the PDF through GMAIL dynamically and they want only the **`Compose Gmail`**. For that I created another button for opening the Compose of Gmail using the Below URL

New Button Name with URL given in it.

2. **`Email PDF`**

`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&shva=1`

With the URL, I can add the TO Address, CC, BCC and Subject and Body directly like below

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&shva=1&to=example1@gmail.com&bcc=example2@gmail.com&body=This%20is%20Body&su=This%20is%20Subject#inbox?compose=new
```

But i cannot add the attachments through URL

Now my question is,

Is there any other Solution to do this kind of scenario?

(or)

Is there any API to get my PDF into the Compose Gmail directly from Salesforce...?

Comment: The Apex email APIs allow you to send [emails with attachments](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_classes_outbound_single). So you could create your own Visualforce page and controller that allows the message text to be added and adds the attachment and then sends the email. But that is somewhat different from using the Gmail UI directly (which AFAIK has no way to specify an attachment).

Comment: Thanks @KeithC for the response. What you said is correct and I already done that VF page and Controller. Whenever i click that button, It will ask for the required fields of TO, CC & BCC etc., and will send the PDF as attachment to gmail ON THE FLY. But they don't want like this. They want the Gmail UI opened on press of a button with the PDF attached to it. Is there any workaround for this?